# Ruby on Rails, how to structure this HAML code to not include some <div> at top level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if the HAML is:

```
.class1
  .class2
    .class3
      %div 
        content... many lines
```

How can it be made so that it doesn't respond with class1 and class2 if it is Ajax?

```
- if !request.xhr?
  .class1
    .class2

.class3
  %div 
    content... many lines
```

won't work, because if not Ajax, then class3 is not a child of class2.  It might have to be something like

```
- if !request.xhr?
  .class1
    .class2
      .class3
        %div 
          content... many lines 
- else
  .class3
    %div 
      content... many lines
```

and it is repeating a lot of code.  Can it be structure within the same file?  Or the second part made into a partial?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you do indeed want a partial - the fact there's no good way to do it with this hierarchy is a good sign to me that you want a partial. Then you can use it elsewhere, easily render a collection, or just generally partition that code.

Also, if this need occurs in other places in your project, you might want to **consider using different default [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)** for your different response formats.

However, you might also consider this pattern:

```
%div{:class => expr ? 'one' : 'two'}
```

which will vary the class based on `expr`. You would still end up with extra divs, but they could be of some other custom class.